# Hasura GraphQL 504 error(Gateway Time-out) while run the query in GraphQL console - API explorer tool

Tags: database, postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have a table with 2.3 millions of data in Postgres DB. While I do the search for user email Id using '_ilike' in Hasura GraphQL console - API explorer tool. Its took too long time to load after 30 seconds its thrown 504 error(Gateway Time-out).Its happens 3/4 times. If I use the same in API in React Application its shown the correct search output within 30 Seconds.

Comment: Hi friend, do you maybe need to increase the timeout or add an index? https://hasura.io/blog/graphql-operation-time-limit-timeout-in-hasura-cloud/

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/queries/performance/

Comment: Hi Arjun, index is also added. still we are facing the same..

Comment: What about increasing the timeout?

Comment: Its take more time to load... Any other options to optimize the query or handle it in frontend like rail on ruby or reactJS..???